# Flutter google Maps ios build fail

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement google maps in my flutter app.
I'm using this version:

```
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+15
```

It works on android, but on ios there's a build fail when trying.

I discovered this:

normally my AppDelegate.swift looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

But when I use this, as the google maps plugin says, the build fails:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR KEY HERE")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping!

Just in case, this is my pubspec yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  firebase_database: ^3.1.1
  cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+6
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.0
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  geolocator: ^5.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  flutter_picker: ^1.1.0
  uuid: ^2.0.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
  path_provider: ^1.5.1
  image: ^2.1.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.2.8
  intl: ^0.16.0
  native_contact_picker: ^0.0.6
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.1+1
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  connectivity: ^0.4.6+1
  flare_splash_screen: ^3.0.0
  algolia: ^0.1.7
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  avatar_glow: ^1.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.22.2
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  camera: ^0.5.7+2
  video_player: ^0.10.5
  story_view: ^0.11.0
  image_crop: ^0.3.1
  file_picker: ^1.4.3+1
  pdf_viewer_plugin: ^1.0.0+2
  flutter_background_geolocation: ^1.4.5
  location_permissions: ^2.0.3
  image_downloader: ^0.19.1
  permission_handler: ^4.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+15
```

And this is the error I get:

```
 /Users/kareldebedts/myapp/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:7:17: error: method does not override any method from its superclass
      override func application(
      ~~~~~~~~      ^
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'camera' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'camera' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've replaced `UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey` with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey` in the function signature. Replace it back to fix the error

Comment: FYI you can use some diff tool to find all places which are different in two code snippets

Comment: Thanks! very strange, cuz I got the snippet from the official google maps package on flutter. But it works! Thanks!